# IOS Keyboard as Gamepad in unity

Tags: unity, ios, virtual-reality, gamepad

So I’ve been messing around in unity lately, and I got a vr headset to mess around as as well(google cardboard). I also want to make my own controller to use with this. To achieve this, I want to use a HID complient chip with a arduino. Basicly, this sends usb keyboard input. I was wondering, will Input.getkey(keycode.whateverkey) work with this? I’m not sure if that will even register on ios, because iOS keyboard is usually separate from the app because it covers the screen.